# Is Raspbian corrupting its self?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am trying to get raspbian (the new pixel version) to boot from a USB Drive, but i have a few issues that i need to work out, but this one i cannot seem to iron out

When raspbian first boot's up after flashing the image to the USB Drive, it works like it should. I resize the partitions with gparted. After rebooting i try to install a few more applications like VNCServer but get this error.

```
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I have looked at solutions but none seem to work
E.G.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/available 
sudo touch /var/lib/dpkg/available
sudo sh -c 'for i in /var/lib/apt/lists/*_Packages; do dpkg --merge-avail "$i"; done'
```

also

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Does anyone know what the issue is and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you shutting down your Pi carefully, i.e. Using sudo shutdown, rather than simply turning power off?

Comment: yes i use sudo shutdown